# Trigger function after window has loaded

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

My smoothscroll plugin is not working because images haven't finished loading before the scrolling kicks in. I tried to wrap the `hashchange` function in a window load function but it doesn't seem to wait for the window to load.

Edit:
*It's not working because the height of the page is incorrect before the page scrolls.*

```
$(document)
.on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function() {
if ( this.hash && this.pathname === location.pathname ) {
$.bbq.pushState( '#/' + this.hash.slice(1) );
return false;
}
})

$(window).load(function() {


$(window).bind('hashchange', function(event) {
  var tgt = location.hash.replace(/^#\/?/,'');
  if ( document.getElementById(tgt) ) {
    $.smoothScroll({scrollTarget: '#' + tgt});
  }
 });

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a plugin such as https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages which I use often - particularly if the page is ajax loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem in past. Where print command was getting executed before loading images in a pop up.  May be it can help you

[Js Fiddle Link][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/685/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your function in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //all your code here
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use the  **onLoad** event of the **body** element. At this event all HTML markup along with the images are loaded on the bowser.

```
function onload()
{
  // your logic here

}
```

Hope it helps...

Note : You can have only one **onload()** method implementation on an HTML document.

For Reference : http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/aspnet/D719120612-Difference-between-document.ready-and-window.onload-or-pageLoad.html